# remove footerview not removing footer view

Tags: android, listview, footer

I want to implement a scenario in which there is an add button which should be displayed at the bottom of screen(visible all the time).after clicking it add button should disappear and instead remove button should be visible at the end of the page(visible at the end of the list).i am able to make add button visible and GONE.but i am adding remove button using a footer to the listview,thus when i remove the footer using listview.removefooter(footer) method the view is not getting refreshed and i can see both add and remove buttons.
i tried 
1)listview.invalidate() method 
2)calling the listadapter again.
Also if i move to previous screen and then re-enter the view gets refreshed.
what should i do.

Comment: try notifyDataSetChanged() for the adapter.

Comment: tried that too.not working. :-(